# Hibernate : delete is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

i am trying to delete object from database using hibernate 
when i click on delete button there is error in hibernate

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: delete is not valid without active transaction
```

here my code when i delete

```
       int id = eStoreUserDTO.geteStoreStoresDTO().getId();
        StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();

        hql.append("select distinct eStoreStoresDTO from EStoreStoresDTO"
                + " eStoreStoresDTO where eStoreStoresDTO.id = "+ id);
        List<EStoreStoresDTO> store = DaoFactory.getDao().selectAllHql(hql + "");

        eStoreUserDTOs.remove(eStoreUserDTO);
        DaoFactory.getDao().delete(eStoreUserDTO);

        EStoreStoresDTO dto = store.get(0);
        DaoFactory.getDao().delete(dto);
```

Delete method:

```
@Override public void delete(Object object) throws DaoException { 
    Session session = null; 
    Transaction transaction = null; 
    try { 
        session = getCurrentSession(); 
        transaction = session.getTransaction(); 
        session.delete(object); 
        transaction.commit(); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        if (transaction != null) { 
            transaction.rollback(); 
        } 
        throw new DaoException(e); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: 1) please copy your code , don't put images. 2) can you add the code of your **DaoFactory.getDao()** ? Thanks

Comment: @Leviand 

` @Override
 public void delete(Object object) throws DaoException {
  Session session = null;
  Transaction transaction = null;
  try {
   session = getCurrentSession();
   transaction = session.getTransaction();
   session.delete(object);
   transaction.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   if (transaction != null) {
    transaction.rollback();
   }
   throw new DaoException(e);
  }
 }`

Comment: @Leviand: Sorry I rejected your edit (at least voted that way). Now only see you took code from the comment, missed that in the comment on the edit. Can unfortunately not 'undo' my vote. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing an CRUD operation on database you should definitely check whether the session you are using is open or not. If it is open then you should also check for whether transaction is active or not.If transaction is active then you can proceed with your operation. But if transaction is not active the you have to manually get a transaction. If session is not open , you should get a new session.

for checking whether session is open or not

```
if(session.isOpen()){
}
```

for getting new session

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
or Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory.openSession();
```

for checking transaction activeness

```
if(transaction.isActive()){}
```

for getting new transaction

```
transaction.begin();
```

You should not begin a transaction when that transaction is active otherwise it will result in error that you are getting

Answer (score 1):

The Exception is straightforward and says:

> delete is not valid without active transaction

So the problem here is that your session doesn't have any open/active `transaction`, and that's due to the line:

```
transaction = session.getTransaction();
```

Where you are getting the `transaction` from the `session` without checking if its active or not.

To avoid this problem you can just begin a new transaction to make sure you don't fall in this case, so change your code to:

```
transaction = session.beginTransaction();
```